# Spark Union vs adding columns using lit in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is a spark related question. I have to add static data to various types of records, each type of record being processed as a different dataframe (say df1, df2, .. df6)
The static data that I intend to add, has to be repeated with all the 6 dataframes.

What would be a more performant way:

1. For each of the 6 dataframes, use:

```
    .witColumn("testA", lit("somethingA"))
    .witColumn("testB", lit("somethingB"))
    .witColumn("testC", lit("somethingC"))
```

or

2. Create a new DF, say staticDF which has all the columns that I intend to append to each of the 6 dataframes and use a union?

or

Any other option that I have not considered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is correct. The second way wouldn't work because union add rows to a dataframe, not columns.

Another way is to use `select` to select all new columns at the same time:

```
df2 = df.select(
    '*',
    lit('somethingA').alias('testA'),
    lit('somethingB').alias('testB'),
    lit('somethingC').alias('testC')
)
```

Comment: What do you think of a join of a broadcasted dataframe containing the literal values only?

Comment: @mike my guess is it will get optimized to this at the end... but I guess performance isn't much of an issue for this trivial operation